# Include the default DirectoryIndex

Tags: php, include, directoryindex

I have `DirectoryIndex index.php` and want to `include './';` But I get `failed to open stream: Is a directory`

Of course I can `include substr($someString, -1)==='/'?$someString.'index.php':$someString;`, but is there an easier way? Maybe something in .htaccess or php.ini?

No is an answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this rather than just simply add the 'index.php' string to the end of the './'. What's wrong with `include './index.php';` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include a directory. PHP will only accept a valid file as an argument for include, so if you want to be able to use "./", or "somedir/" and have it find the index.php file in that dir, you could always write a function which takes the dir as an argument and returns a full path to the index file within.

Something like:

```
function index($dir){
   return substr($dir, -1) === '/' ? $dir.'index.php' : $dir;
}
```

Then you could call `include index("./");` or some other directory name and have it return the proper string.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to include from current directory you do not need any path :

```
include 'index.php';
```

else if you want to include from remote files you should start from http

```
include 'http://www.example.com/file.txt';
```

Attn : Windows versions of PHP prior to PHP 4.3.0 do not support access of remote files via this function, even if allow_url_fopen is enabled.

else if you want to include from relative path you can start `'/`... then you start from your host root or `'../`...... for stating from sub directory .

Comment: You didn't answer the question. The specific directory is unknown. I want something that will make a directory turn into a index file, easier than `substr($someString, -1)==='/'?$someString.'index.php':$someString;` Probably something in .htaccess or php.ini.